# Adobe Cirrus can it be used for commercial use?

Tags: adobe, p2p, adobe-cirrus

can anyone tell me for certain if are you allowed to use Adobe Cirrus service (p2p) in commercial applications or websites? for instance you have a online game.

all the threads and articles i have found are over 4years old (stating that) so was wondering if things had changed since then?

Answer (score 0):

have done bit more digging the only thing i have found was on the Adobe Cirrus labs page:

> What are my options to use RTMFP in my commercial application?
>   Developers can use Adobe Media Server to develop and deploy RTMFP
>   applications.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/